# JPA query without using primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Using JPA2.0 (via Hibernate 4), I can query the database for a record where the query criteria is the primary key by using EntityManager.find(java.lang.Class entityClass, java.lang.Object primaryKey). But if the query criteria isn't a primary key (for example, select all records whose city value is 'london'), do I have to create a TypedQuery and explicitly provide the SQL statement? Is there any best practice I should adopt?

Comment: suggest you read up on TypedQuery and what is the query passed into it. That is not SQL, more like JPQL

Comment: I understand that, but am I right in thinking that I have to use TypedQuery, there's no other way? I'm happy to do so, I just want to ensure I get maximum use out of Hibernate/JPA and adopt the best practice, whatever that may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JPA Criteria API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html) provides you with a level of compile-time safety you won't get with constructing your own dynamic queries (using jpql or sql). Especially when a lot of conditions start to creep in (optional fields, conditional subqueries, ...) it can become very easy to make mistakes.

The Criteria API can be more complex to write (especially for simple queries), and you need to create some plumbing code around the criteria API to make it a truly dynamic and easy to use language. It doesn't really offer it out of the box.

Some people like working with the Criteria API, while others prefer named queries / JPQL.

Comment: That's just what I needed, thank you. I will go with the CriteriaQuery approach.